# How to do the unit testing for the simple silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, selenium, nunit

I am having simple Calculator application. In this i have one Method. I don't know how to test that method nu? Can you please any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please any one help me. It's very urgent.

Comment: Selenium does not support and/or work with Silverlight.

Comment: can you please any say some tool for perform the unit test for the silverlight application

Answer (score 0):

There is a Silverlight Unit Testing Framework included in the Silverlight Toolkit, which is available [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). More information on the unit testing framework can be found [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/).

One alternative approach that I often use myself is to separate the non-UI Silverlight code into for example a [portable class library](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) that can be referenced from Silverlight applications as well as regular .NET applications or WP7 applications. Then I create a normal [NUnit](http://nunit.com/) .NET Framework test library to unit test the components of my portable class library.